# How to orchestrate global network of groups / facilitators?

Tags: community-organizing

I'm ramping up global [APIOps network](https://medium.com/apiops), which consists of local independent groups in various cities. We have now groups in 4 cities. Our current growth plan contains elements which enables us to scale network to 13 countries. Major element in the growth plan is Demola Network which is global innovation platform with around 20 sites in 13 countries. The problem is not tools — those are probably there for all the needs we have. Issue that is rising is related to social network and management ([more info](https://medium.com/apiops/growth-issues-orchestrating-network-of-community-facilitators-be78a83e47b7)). I now have 8 local group facilitators (2 / each group). Soon I'll have 20-30 facilitators.

What kind of practices would help to manage the facilitator network?

Links to good resources on community management strategy would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you need to rewrite your question. The only sentence regarding the issue you are having is *Issue that is rising is related to social network and management* and that is extremely vague. The rest is references to software which seem irrelevant to the question, and a link where we are supposed to go to read what the issue is. That is not how SE sites work: you questions need to have enough information so that we can read and answer it here. Of course you can leave that link in for 'more details', but currently your question is "Unclear what you are asking" Please [edit] your question.